# Dropdown List selected value display only one using Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i have load the DropDownList successfully. all student numbers i have loaded when i select the  student no relavent student name should diplay on the below textbox. but now if select any number only one student name is shown John name only. if i select diffent student numbers. i don't know why.

**DropDownList Load code**

string cmdstr = "select id from records";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, con);

```
        con.Open();

        read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DropDownList1.Items.Clear();

        while (read.Read())
        {
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(read["id"].ToString());

        }
        con.Close();
```

**Selected data**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" ViewStateMode="Enabled" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>

  if (Page.IsPostBack == true)
                {
    string cmdstr = "select firstname from records where id = " + 
    DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, con);
    con.Open();
    read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (read.Read())
    {
     name.Text = read["firstname"].ToString();
    }
    con.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a example: evt. this helps

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFruits" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Please Select" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Mango" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Apple" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Orange" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Button Text="Get Selected Text Value" runat="server" OnClientClick="return GetSelectedTextValue()" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetSelectedTextValue() {
        var ddlFruits = document.getElementById("<%=ddlFruits.ClientID %>");
        var selectedText = ddlFruits.options[ddlFruits.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
        var selectedValue = ddlFruits.value;
        alert("Selected Text: " + selectedText + " Value: " + selectedValue);
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

You can get the value from the list or the selected text (innerHTML) !

Comment: so how to load the database table to do this.

Comment: You'd still use your code to load the dropdown list on Page_Load